# find command equivalent to ls -p

Tags: command-line, find, ls

Nee to **find** command to generate output exactly as if `ls -p` would generate?

With `find /path/to/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1  -exec basename {} \;` the directories don't have trailing slash.. i need the output folder names to have trailing slash

**sample output:**

```
folder 1/
my-file-1.sh
```

**find** command to list directory contents without full path and folders with a trailing slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bsh
$ find /path/to -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec sh -c '
     [ -d "$1" ] && printf "%s/\n" "${1##*/}" || printf "%s\n" "${1##*/}" ' _ {} \;
aDirectory/
afile
```

**Explanations:**

- `[ -d "$1" ]`, this checks if its a *directory*, if yes then run followed `printf`:

  ```
  printf "%s/\n" "${1##*/}"
  ```

  else, run below `printf`:

  ```
  printf "%s\n" "${1##*/}"
  ```

  - `${1##*/}`: this removes longest match of everything `*` till last slash `/` seen start from begging of the file/directory path, which it will result only last directory/file name only.

Answer (score 0):

At least with GNU find, you can use the built-in `-printf` e.g.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f/\n' -o -type f -printf '%f\n'
```